# zk mvc 2 .zul share same controller

Tags: java, spring, zk

If I have 2 .zul, one has a listbox, and another is the modal window. can they use the same controller? I just can't get it work.

the question basically resume at, do I have to use `apply="myController"` in both .zul?
if I do that, I get nullpointerException at `myList`, because I think zk is instantiating 2 controller objects, and the modal doesn't exist `myList`. but If I don't apply the controller at modal.zul, nothing happens when I press buttons.

how can I make 2 .zul use same instance of controller?

mail.zul

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" ?>
<zk>
    <hlayout>
    <div id="winDiv" apply="com.company.controller.ProductController">
        <vbox>
            <listbox id="myList" width="690px" height="300px" >
                <listhead>
                    <listheader hflex="min" label="id" sort="auto(id)" />
                    <listheader hflex="2" label="name" sort="auto(name)" />
                    <listheader hflex="4" label="description" sort="auto(description)" />
                                        <listheader hflex="min" label="opcion"/>
                                </listhead>
            </listbox>
        </vbox>
    </div>
            <button label="new" id="new"/>
        </hlayout>
</zk>
```

the modal.zul

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<window id="modalProductType" title="Nuevo tipo de producto" border="normal" width="420px"
    closable="true" position="center,center" **apply="com.company.controller.ProductController"**>

    <grid>
        <columns>
                <column hflex="1"/>
                <column hflex="2"/>
        </columns>
        <rows>
                <row>
                    Clave:
                     <textbox hflex="1" value="@{product.id}" readonly="true"/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    Nombre:
                     <textbox id="txtname" value="@{product.name}" hflex="1" tabindex="1" />
                </row>
                <row>
                     Description:
                      <textbox value="@{product.description}" rows="5" hflex="1" tabindex="2" />
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                        <hlayout>
                            <button width="100px" id="save" label="Aceptar"/>
                            <button width="100px" label="close"/>
                        </hlayout>
                   </cell>
                </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</window>
```

ProductController.java

```
public class ProductTypeController extends SelectorComposer {
@WiredVariable
    private ProductTypeService productTypeService;

@Wire
    private Listbox myList;

//methods...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT recommended

1. To avoid concurrency issues (Refer [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer#Apply_Composer_Instances)) For eg. if same controller instance is applied to multiple views, the wired components will point to the last view causing erratic behavior of UI. It is easier to just use different instances instead of coding for concurrency issues and making controller thread safe.
2. To avoid memory leak. For eg. if same controller instance is applied to two completely different views and components from both views are wired in it, then if one of the view is not being used its components wired will still not be released causing memory leak.

Comment: hmm, if I use 2 controllers, one for modal, other for list. how can I pass the information caputures with the modal controller to the list controller to reflect the changes?

Comment: You can use `EventQueue` or simply post event along ith the data to the div to which your list controller is applied. Personally I will recommeend using `EventQueue` and for your case refer to a sample [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues#Example:_interactive_between_multiple_ZUL_pages)

Comment: actually this should be part of answer. it was very helpful